# Google Map API with jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-tabs

I am implementing Google Map with jQuery tab but not getting proper display.

I have tried this code to reCenter the map onclick of tab ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#tab6").click(function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger('location-canvas', 'resize');
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            map.setZoom(16);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

but didn't work.

I am using this tab script: [Simple jQuery Responsive Tabs Interface Plugin - jQueryTab](http://goo.gl/CpR5lU)

And My JSFiddle is: [Code](http://goo.gl/Uxeymh)

I will appreciate If you guide me and help me fix this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you trigger the event for `'location-canvas'` , what is only a string, you must supply the `google.maps.Map`-instance as argument
2. triggering the resize-event onclick may be too early, use the `after`-method of the plugin instead.

   ```
   after: function(){if($(this).text()==='Google Map'){ 
       //map must be the google.maps.Map-instance and available here
       center=map.getCenter();
       google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
       map.setCenter(center);                                             
   }}
   ```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xzVpW/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xzVpW/)

Note: the `map`-variable is not available inside the after-method. In my modified fiddle I stored the instance inside  `$('#location-canvas').data`