# Correctly implementing a JQuery Google map plugin with the UI Tabs plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I can't get to see the google map on my Jquery ui tabs that I created, I can see the frame but no map location or anything. What Do I need to do to fix this?

What I tried to do  is a Jquery ui Tabs i.e 3 tabs and one has a small JavaScript  Google Map

```js
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>    
        
          <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  }); 
}); 
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.0333, 45.3500),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  
      </script>


      </head>

      <body>
      <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> 
  </div>

</div>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="img1" alt="Cinque Terre" width="800" height="490">
        <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#map">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>l lorem ipsum jfsdjkng jkgndksjgn djkndsjkgns lorem ipsum jfsdjkng jkgndksjgn djkndsjkgnsorem ipsum jfsdjkng jkgndksjgn djkndsjkgns
</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <form role="form">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">lorem Star 
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">lorem Star
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">lorem Star
    </label>
  </form>
  <br>
  </div>
  
     <div id="map"></div>

</div>
```

```css
 #map {
        width: 300px;
        height: 280px;
      }
```

Comment: Could someone direct me to an example or a page which could give me a clue in how I would figure this problem out

Comment: Search StackOverflow for similar (or duplicate) questions.

Comment: You may want to check question [22111346 - google-map-api-with-jquery-tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111346/google-map-api-with-jquery-tab).

Comment: @LexJulienne I cant get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Call initialize() inside the $(document).ready function and remove google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
Also, give some width and height to the #map div in your css, if you haven't done this already

Comment: Yeah I have   #map {
        width: 300px;
        height: 280px;
      }

Comment: How would I place the map plugin inside a jquery ui tab ??